# Capturing audio out in Android and writing as a mp3

Tags: audio, mp3

I want to be able to capture all the audio that would normally play through the speaker on my Android phone and write that stream as some sort of audio file.

The reason I would like to do this is that I want to capture Subsonic streams and write them to a file on my phone. Then I can attach it my car stereo as a USB mass storage and play these streams.

Is there a way with or without root to do this?

Comment: Subsonic caches mp3's to the memory card.  So in this case, why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Subsonic Music Streamer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.subsonic.androidapp), one of the application features is precisely what you are looking for:

> Songs are cached for offline playback. Supports mp3, ogg, aac, flac, wma. Most video formats supported too.